# split torch::Tensor into std::vector<torch::Tensor>

Tags: c++, libtorch

```
A = torch::randn({16, 3, 3, 224});
```

I want to split A into std::vector<torch::Tensor> whose length is 16 and each element has torch::Tensor with [3, 3, 224].

```
std::vector<torch::Tensor> B = torch::split(A, 16, 0);
```

To do this, I ran above code, but the result is the length of vector is 1 and the element has [16, 3, 3, 224] dimension.

How can i achieve desirable result?

Comment: I believe the function definition is [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp#L2510). How about `torch::split(A, 1, 0);`? 1 element for a slice on dimension 0.